# Does bit-shifting always take the Endian architecture into consideration?

Tags: c#, c++, bit-shift, endianness

Suppose I'm porting code from C++ and need to emulate the same Bit-shifting techniques in C#:

Whenever I perform bitshifting, do I ever have to consider the Endain-ness of the architecture?

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not.  In both C++ and C#, You can think of bit-shifting entirely in terms of the number being stored, disregarding the endianness of the architecture.

Answer (score 3):

No. Bitshifting is a purely algebraic operation. It's no more platform dependent than multiplication by two.

What *is* platform dependent is the result of interpreting a variable as an array of characters.

Comment: If I read the bytes individually, or increment a PTR will that give me the same results, or can a PTR "see" the endianness?

Comment: @makerofthings7: What is "PTR"? What do you mean by "the same results"? Reinterpreting an object as an array of bytes shows you the binary representation of the object, including endianness...

Comment: I was referring to an in memory pointer in unsafe mode in c#.  Im not sure if I have a 64 bit word and increment the pointer by one what I'll see.